# WordPress - Database FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have data in post_content of table - wp_posts like this :

```
[["ROLL NO.","SID NO","N A M E","M/F"],
["1","1801031101","K. NISHA GOVIND","F"],
["2","1809031101","PATEL RAJ DIRAJ","M"],
["3","1801031901","SHARMA CHARMI J","F"],
["4","1891031101","PATEL HIRAL J","F"],
["5","1801031301","SHAH BRIJESH V","M"],
["6","1801031709","PAREKH HITESH R","M"]]
```

Now I want to compare SID NO and tried it like :

**Option 1:**

```
$results_match_roll = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE find_in_set('.$rollNumber.', post_content) ');
```

**Option 2:**

```
$results_match_roll = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%$rollNumber);
```

But no luck. Please guide me through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FIND_IN_SET` finds the values separated by comma. Since your `SID NO` has `"` you need to check like below. That is include double quote before and after of `SID NO`.

```
$results_match_roll = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE find_in_set('\"$rollNumber\"', post_content) ");
```